# How to structure table to make it smaller?

Tags: tables

I have made the following table[image]

It corresponds to the following code:

```
   \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,marginparwidth=1.5cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Main economic evaluation measures}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{l c*{6}{S}}
\toprule
 & {Mean (\%)} & {Std. (\%)} & {IR} & {Max 1M Loss(\%)} & {Max DD. (\%)} & {Turnover(\%)} \\
 \hline
 & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\hspace{0.3cm}\bfseries Mean variance factor timing strategy}\\
 \addlinespace[0.2ex]
 \hline
 \addlinespace[0.2ex]
  OLS3 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  OLSAll & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  EN FV& 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  EN TSS&0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  GLM FV&0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  GLM TSS & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN1 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
    NN2 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN5 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN10 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN15 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  Comb & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  CombNN & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
 \hline
\addlinespace[0.2ex]
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{\hspace{0.3cm}\bfseries Top prediction factor timing strategy}\\
 \addlinespace[0.2ex]
 \hline
  OLS3 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  OLSAll & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  EN FV& 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  EN TSS&0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  GLM FV&0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  GLM TSS & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN1 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
    NN2 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN5 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN10 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN15 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  Comb & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  CombNN & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
   \hline
 \addlinespace[0.2ex]
&  \multicolumn{5}{c}{\hspace{0.3cm}\bfseries Benchmark strategies}\\
 \addlinespace[0.2ex]
 \hline
 SMB & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  HML & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  MOM& 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  Multi &0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  Factor Mom&0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Obviously, this doesn't look very nice and it also does not fit on the page. Initially, I was thinking to make the OLS3, OLSAll etc. as column labels, but this wouldn't be consistent with the lower part of the table. Does anyone know how to change either the structure/architecture of my table, or perhaps change something else to make it look nicer?

Comment: Have you considered turning this page to landscape?

Comment: the column widths are dominated by the headings, if you wrote these over two lines  and/or used a smaller font for the heading you could get all the data columns to be the same width.

Comment: also never use `\resizebox` on tables

Comment: Please always test posted documents, the posted code does not produce the image shown and makes errors `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option 'H'.` and `! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 \resizebox`

Comment: @David Carlisle I tried writing the column heading over 2 lines, and ommitting the resizebox; this already made it a bit smaller. I will try to fix the posted code: it was a bit difficult to see which packages it was using as I loaded a lot in total.

Comment: @Rik but it is easy for you to test the document before posting, surely? (you are missing float and graphicx packages)

Comment: Yes sorry for that: I included everything that was missing just now. I noticed that by changing \linespread{1.5} to \linespread{1}, it fits on one page, though according to the thesis regulations at my university the linespace should be 1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from avoiding increased `\linespread`, I suggest some improvements:

1. in order to make all columns equal width, if possible, I use the widest label, in this case “Turnover”, with a suitable temporary command;
2. the overlong header “Max 1M Loss” can be merged with the following column, at the expense of a new header row;
3. the percentage symbols are better placed in a new header row;
4. use the appropriate specification for each `S` column (I left all of them `1.2`, not knowing the actual figures in your real world table);
5. use `\midrule`, possibly with a thickness specification instead of `\hline`;
6. remove the padding at the left and right of the table.

Besides this, you had a wrong specification of columns, with a spurious second `c` column. The `\multicolumn{5}{c}{...}` lines should have `6`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array, booktabs,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

% a temporary command
\newcommand{\hd}[1]{{\makebox[\widthof{Turnover}]{#1}}}

\caption{Main economic evaluation measures}
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
 & \hd{Mean} & \hd{Std.} & \hd{IR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Max} & {Turnover} \\
\cmidrule{5-6}
 &        &        &      & \hd{1M Loss} & \hd{DD.}   &            \\
 & {(\%)} & {(\%)} &      & {(\%)}    & {(\%)}      & {(\%)}     \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries Mean variance factor timing strategy}\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
  OLS3 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  OLSAll & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  EN FV& 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  EN TSS&0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  GLM FV&0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  GLM TSS & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN1 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
    NN2 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN5 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN10 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN15 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  Comb & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  CombNN & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries Top prediction factor timing strategy}\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
  OLS3 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  OLSAll & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  EN FV& 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  EN TSS&0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  GLM FV&0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  GLM TSS & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN1 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
    NN2 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN5 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN10 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN15 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  Comb & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  CombNN & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
&  \multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries Benchmark strategies}\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
 SMB & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  HML & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  MOM& 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  Multi &0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  Factor Mom&0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

If the table results again too wide, you can try `\small` or `\footnotesize` instead of `\resizebox`.

[image]

If you want to fill the text width, use `tabular*`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array, booktabs,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

% a temporary command
\newcommand{\hd}[1]{{\makebox[\widthof{Turnover}]{#1}}}

\caption{Main economic evaluation measures}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
 & \hd{Mean} & \hd{Std.} & \hd{IR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Max} & {Turnover} \\
\cmidrule{5-6}
 &        &        &      & \hd{1M Loss} & \hd{DD.}   &            \\
 & {(\%)} & {(\%)} &      & {(\%)}    & {(\%)}      & {(\%)}     \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries Mean variance factor timing strategy}\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
  OLS3 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  OLSAll & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  EN FV& 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  EN TSS&0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  GLM FV&0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  GLM TSS & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN1 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
    NN2 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN5 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN10 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN15 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  Comb & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  CombNN & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries Top prediction factor timing strategy}\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
  OLS3 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  OLSAll & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  EN FV& 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  EN TSS&0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  GLM FV&0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  GLM TSS & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN1 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
    NN2 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN5 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN10 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  NN15 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  Comb & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  CombNN & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
&  \multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries Benchmark strategies}\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
 SMB & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  HML & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  MOM& 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  Multi &0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
  Factor Mom&0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If your school regulations impose one and a half spacing, cheat and add

```
\linespread{1.4}\selectfont
```

after the caption and experiment with the factor until your table fits the page.